# passing authentication info in html form

Tags: html, http, authentication

hie

i have a html form and while posting a request to a url i also want to pass crendtials using basic-auth

can anybody please share a code example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the url of the form's action attribute to

```
http://username:password@www.yourserver.com/somewebpage.html
```

but I don't think this will work with Internet Explorer. There were some spammers abusing this and Microsoft disabled it.